# AngularJS: ui-switch not working

Tags: angularjs, switchery

I am using angularjs version 1.6.4 with [NGSwitchery](https://github.com/servergrove/NgSwitchery). After page load i am getting the input as i mentioned in the comments below on each models. But ui-switch is not working (not getting on/off) at the start according to model values. When i click any switch than that specific switch get enabled and on the basis of that model value also change with 0/1. What am i doing wrong.

If i remove ui-switch, i can see that checkbox is working fine after page load  e.g with value 1 it is marked and with 0 it's not.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" ui-switch ng-model="model.user.hide_phone" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
{{model.user.hide_phone}} <!-- for testing input: 1 -->

<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" ui-switch ng-model="model.user.hide_address" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
{{model.user.hide_address}} <!-- for testing input: 0 -->

<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" ui-switch ng-model="model.user.hide_me" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
{{model.user.hide_me}} <!-- for testing input: 1 -->
```